# Module Resolution does not work in vue project (monorepo)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have the following structure (monorepo):

```
/packages/vue-project
/packages/i18n
/packages/i18n/nl (contains index.ts with export of json files)
```

*/packages/vue-project/tsconfig.json*

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "@company/translations/*": [
    "../i18n/*"
  ]
},
```

PhpStorm recognises the `@company/translations/nl` export, but when I run `yarn serve` the follow error occurs:

```
This dependency was not found:

* @company/translations/nl in ./src/i18n.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @company/translations/nl
```

The i18n.ts contains the import

```
import nl from '@company/translations/nl';
```

Comment: Since you asked this question one year ago. I'm curious, did you resolve the issue?